# Using the biblatex entry type to select the right field

Tags: biblatex, titles

I need to selectively retrieve titles from references using biblatex, based on the entry type.

That is, for article, incollection, inbook, and similar entry types describing a smaller item published within a larger one, I want the title of the book or journal *in which the work appeared* (ie the booktitle or journal field), rather than the title of the article itself. For books and other monographs I just want the normal title.

I can see from the biblatex doc how to selectively print references by entry type, but I can't see how you get the entry type from an individual key. Is there something like `\getentrytype{<key>}` that will return the string 'article', 'incollection, 'book', etc, so that I can then make LaTeX decide programmatically which field to retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that if you don't need the normal behaviour of `labeltitle` (so this idea is probably a non-starter with author-title-based styles) would be to reconfigure `labeltitle` resolution so that you get back the desired type of title

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeltitle[article]{%
  \field{journaltitle}
}

\DeclareLabeltitle[inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{%
  \field{booktitle}
  \field{maintitle}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\citetitle{sigfridsson}

\citetitle{worman}

\citetitle{nussbaum}

\citetitle{geer}

\citetitle{pines}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Journal of Computational Chemistry//Cast of Character//Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’//Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music//Studies in Medieval Jewish History and Literature]

---

If the `labeltitle` solution does not work for you, you will have to roll a manual version of that approach.

The following implements a `\petercitetitle` that usually prints the `title` field, but can be configured to print a different field for on a per-type basis.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{petercitetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\petercitetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifbibmacroundef{peter:citetitle:\strfield{entrytype}}
     {\printfield[petercitetitle]{title}}
     {\usebibmacro*{peter:citetitle:\strfield{entrytype}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


% you can define exceptions to printing 'title'
% for type <type> by defining a bibmacro called
% 'peter:citetitle:<type>'
% the macros usually have the same structure, so this
% could be packed up into a macro

\newbibmacro*{peter:citetitle:article}{%
  \printfield[petercitetitle]{journaltitle}}

\newbibmacro*{peter:citetitle:inbook}{%
  \printfield[petercitetitle]{booktitle}}

\letbibmacro*{peter:citetitle:incollection}{peter:citetitle:inbook}
\letbibmacro*{peter:citetitle:inproceedings}{peter:citetitle:inbook}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\petercitetitle{sigfridsson}

\petercitetitle{worman}

\petercitetitle{nussbaum}

\petercitetitle{geer}

\petercitetitle{pines}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Journal of Computational Chemistry//The Cast of Character//Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’//Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music//Studies in Medieval Jewish History and Literature]

Here `\strfield{entrykey}` is similar to what your `\getentrytype{<key>}` would do (except it always applies to the current `<key>`, you can't easily extract the entry type of an entry that is not currently being processed, you'd have to switch over to that entry with `\entrydata`).

Comment: I'm experimenting with the options. Many thanks for this.